# double press key in autohotkey results ctrl+key

Tags: autohotkey

My Ctrl key has broken. I am looking for the following solution:

x x = Ctrl-x

where x is an arbitrary key (including F1, F2,....)

In other words, if I press an arbitary key (say x) two consecutive times (that is the time between two press is smaller that certain amount) I can obtain Ctrl-x.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Which keys exactly do you want this to be possible with? You'd need to make a list.

Comment: @0x464e Thank you for you reply, I mainly need this for the keys: a, x, c, z, f, b, s, w, q, v, g, h, t, r, e, k, i, ], SPACE, F1, F2, F3, F4.

Comment: What's your plan to retain the original functionality of the key? Assuming you'd want that.

Comment: @0x464e, Of course I want to preserve the original function of the key. More precisely, if a double keypress is not detected, I would like that these keys behave their original functions.

Comment: Sure, but it's not that easy. What happens from first press? Nothing until after x amount of time has passed? What about if another key is pressed before that x amount of time runs out? I would probably recommend making some toggle on/off for the doubletap behavior. Maybe only while some other key is held down as well, or a simple on/off switch, or something.

Comment: If another key is pressed before that amount of time then this means that double keypress has not been detected, hence the both keys are assumed to behave their original functions.

Comment: But you'll still have to block the initial press. So you can't actually retain the keys' real original functionalities. Best you could do (as far as I can tell) is listen for a new key press after a key with a double tap hotkey is pressed once. If one occurs, then consume that keypress, then send the double tap key's press, and then the new key press. Sounds like a nightmare. And ideally this should be implemented at hardware driver level, because otherwise I'd guarantee you running into some trouble. At least with apps that use their own methods detecting input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. Just replace the value of `cooldown` with how long you'll accept between button presses.

```
CtrlReplacement(key) {
    static cooldown := 1000 ; milliseconds
    If (A_PriorHotkey == A_ThisHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < cooldown) {
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{%key%}{Ctrl Up}
    } Else {
        Send, {%key%}
    }
}
keys := ["a","x","c","z","f","b","s","w","q","v","g","h","t","r","e","k","i","]","SPACE","F1","F2","F3","F4"]
For _,key in keys {
    func := Func("CtrlReplacement").Bind(key)
    Hotkey, $%key%, % func
}
```

#### A little explanation.

We're using the [Hotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotkey.htm) function rather than the typical `F1::` ([Double-colon label](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)) syntax in order to generate these at runtime instead of compile-time (which makes the code much smaller and without duplication). You *can* write them all out instead, but it'd be a hassle.

The `$` before the `%key%` means that a virtual press of the key won't also trigger this hotkey (i.e., the hotkey won't trigger itself), so if you wrote them all manually, you'd need a `$` before each one.

Then the function checks whether the hotkey is the same as the one that was previously pressed and if the time since the previous one was pressed is less than a preset time (`cooldown`). If so, it send the ctrl+key combination. Otherwise, it just sends the key itself (thus retaining the original functionality of the key).

You could also adjust the function so that it waits until the cooldown has passed, and if the key wasn't pressed again, *then and only then* does it send the original key. Though that would require a bit more finesse. If that's what you were intending then let me know and I can try to help you there as well.

### Edit

I went ahead and made that version anyway :)

```
SendDefaultKey(key) {
    Send, {%key%}
}
CtrlReplacement(key) {
    static cooldown := 300 ; milliseconds
    static keyFunctions := []
    If (!keyFunctions.HasKey(key)) {
        keyFunctions[key] := Func("SendDefaultKey").Bind(key)
    }
    func := keyFunctions[key]
    If (A_PriorHotkey == A_ThisHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < cooldown) {
        SetTimer, % func, Off
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{%key%}{Ctrl Up}
    } Else {
        SetTimer, % func, -%cooldown%
    }
}
Setup() {
    keys := ["a","x","c","z","f","b","s","w","q","v","g","h","t","r","e","k","i","]","SPACE","F1","F2","F3","F4"]
    For _,key in keys {
        func := Func("CtrlReplacement").Bind(key)
        Hotkey, $%key%, % func
    }
}
Setup()
```

This version will—for the keys that have been mapped—wait until the cooldown has expired, and if they key has not been pressed again (and in immediate succession), it will send the raw key once. Otherwise, it will send the ctrl+key

### Edit 2

In light of the OP's comment, here is a third version which sets the delay for (almost) all keyboard characters, which makes the ctrl variant a bit more ergonomic/intuitive.

```
global keyDelay := 300 ; milliseconds
RunFuncWithDelay(func) {
    SetTimer, % func, -%keyDelay%
}
SendDefaultKey(key) {
    Send, {%key%}
}
CtrlReplacement(key) {
    static keyFunctions := []
    If (!keyFunctions.HasKey(key)) {
        keyFunctions[key] := Func("SendDefaultKey").Bind(key)
    }
    func := keyFunctions[key]
    If (A_PriorHotkey == A_ThisHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < keyDelay) {
        SetTimer, % func, Off
        Send, {Ctrl Down}{%key%}{Ctrl Up}
    } Else {
        RunFuncWithDelay(func)
    }
}
Setup() {
    ; Add/Remove affected characters here
    allkeys := ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","``","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","=","F1","F2","F3","F4","F5","F6","F7","F8","F9","F10","F11","F12","~","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","[","]","{","}","\","|",";",":","'","""",",","<",".",">","/","?","ENTER","DEL","SPACE","TAB","Numpad0","Numpad1","Numpad2","Numpad3","Numpad4","Numpad5","Numpad6","Numpad7","Numpad8","Numpad9","NumpadAdd","NumpadClear","NumpadDel","NumpadDiv","NumpadDot","NumpadDown","NumpadEnd","NumpadEnter","NumpadHome","NumpadIns","NumpadLeft","NumpadMult","NumpadRight","NumpadSub","NumpadUp"]
    ; The characters below will overwrite the above mappings
    ctrlkeys := ["a","b","c","e","f","g","h","i","k","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","z","F1","F2","F3","F4","]","SPACE"]
    For _,key in allkeys {
        keyfunc := Func("SendDefaultKey").Bind(key)
        delayfunc := Func("RunFuncWithDelay").Bind(keyfunc)
        Hotkey, $%key%, % delayfunc
    }
    For _,key in ctrlkeys {
        keyNum := Asc(key)
        func := Func("CtrlReplacement").Bind(key)
        Hotkey, $%key%, % func
    }
}
Setup()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second solution corresponds better to my initial question. A possible improvement is to wait until the countdown expires before the next non-keys are typed. Because if for example you press "f" then "," (where "," is pressed before countdown, the result will be ",f" instead of "f,".  Thank you again.

Comment: One way you could do that relatively simply would be do add a second array in `Setup()` with all of those keys and then bind the SendDefaultKey function with each of those, using the `SetTimer, % sendDefaultKeyFunc, -%cooldown%` to have the delay be the same. I neglected to mention in the post, but a negative value for the number in `SetTimer` makes the timer only fire once after the delay has expired.

Comment: I've added a version that I believe complies with what your additional improvement suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much. The only problem that I encountered is that if you type a non-Ctrlkey twice very fast (say the letter `l` , you get only one `l`). Thank you any way, I accepted your answer.

Comment: My idea has some limitations, in order that the typing process be smooth `keyDelay` should not be too large, otherwise there are annoying lags. If `keyDelay` is too small, it is hard to fire `CtrlReplacement` function. I found the experimental value 100-125 is fairly good, both it depends on the natural typing speed of each person. And even with this values one experiments unintended firing of `CtrlReplacement` and `SendDefaultKey` functions. Of course these limitations and inconveniences are caused by my idea not your code.

Comment: I set it up that way because I figured it would be more consistent. If you'd like the behavior you're suggesting, you can make `RunFuncWithDelay` take the key as a parameter and move the `keyfunc := Func("SendDefaultKey").Bind(key)` inside `RunFuncWithDelay`. The reason it's only launching once is because the SetTimer is getting a reference to the exact same function instance. If the function creation is moved to inside the method itself, it'll always be a new reference and the timers will run in parallel (You'll want to make the reference in `CtrlReplacement` like Edit 1 if you do so)